# On a two dimensional grid is there a formula I can use to spiral coordinates in an outward pattern?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I don't know exactly how to describe it, but in a programmatic way I want to spiral outward from coordinates 0,0 to infinity (for practical purposes, though really I only need to go to about +/-100,000:+/-100,000)

So if this is my grid:

```
[-1, 1][ 0, 1][ 1, 1][ 2, 1]
[-1, 0][ 0, 0][ 1, 0][ 2, 0]
[-1,-1][ 0,-1][ 1,-1][ 2,-1]
```

I want to spiral in an order sort of like:

```
[7][8][9][10]
[6][1][2][11]
[5][4][3][12]
etc...
```

Is there a formula or method of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42942/how-can-i-index-2-dimensional-points-starting-at-the-origin-and-going-outwards

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here’s a recipe for finding the coordinates of your position after $n$ steps along the spiral.

It’s simpler to number the positions on the spiral starting at $0$: position $0$ is $\langle 0,0\rangle$, the origin, position $1$ is $\langle 1,0\rangle$, position $2$ is $\langle 1,-1\rangle$, and so on. Using $R,D,L$, and $U$ to indicate steps Right, Down, Left, and Up, respectively, we see the following pattern:

$$RD\,|LLUU\,\|\,RRRDDD\,|LLLLUUUU\,\|\,RRRRRDDDDD\,|LLLLLLUUUUUU\;\|\dots\;,$$

or with exponents to denote repetition, $R^1D^1|L^2U^2\|R^3D^3|L^4U^4\|R^5D^5|L^6U^6\|\dots\;$. I’ll call each $RDLU$ group a *block*; the first block is the initial $RDLLUU$, and I’ve displayed the first three full blocks above.

Clearly the first $m$ blocks comprise a total of $2\sum_{k=1}^{2m}k=2m(2m+1)$ steps. It’s also not hard to see that the $k$-th block is $R^{2k+1}D^{2k+1}L^{2k+2}U^{2k+2}$, so that the net effect of the block is to move you one step up and to the left. Since the starting position after $0$ blocks is $\langle 0,0\rangle$, the starting position after $k$ full blocks is $\langle -k,k\rangle$.

Suppose that you’ve taken $n$ steps. There is a unique even integer $2k$ such that $$2k(2k+1)<n\le(2k+2)(2k+3)\;;$$ at this point you’ve gone through $k$ blocks plus an additional $n-2k(2k+1)$ steps. After some straightforward but slightly tedious algebra we find that you’re at

$$\begin{cases}
\langle n-4k^2-3k,k\rangle,&\text{if }2k(2k+1)<n\le(2k+1)^2\\
\langle k+1,4k^2+5k+1-n\rangle,&\text{if }(2k+1)^2<n\le 2(k+1)(2k+1)\\
\langle 4k^2+7k+3-n,-k-1\rangle,&\text{if }2(k+1)(2k+1)<n\le4(k+1)^2\\
\langle -k-1,n-4k^2-9k-5\rangle,&\text{if }4(k+1)^2<n\le2(k+1)(2k+3)\;.
\end{cases}$$

To find $k$ easily, let $m=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$. If $m$ is odd, $k=\frac12(m-1)$. If $m$ is even, and $n\ge m(m+1)$, then $k=\frac{m}2$; otherwise, $k=\frac{m}2-1$.

Comment: Yikes that is a bit more complex than I expected, hopefully I can put it to use!

Comment: Is there a generalization/extension of this to an $d$-dimensional outward spiral?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 It doesn't seem obvious how this spiral would go. Could you provide an example for a 3x3x3 cube?

Comment: @Kaligule ... i agree. not at all obvious. thus my question

Answer (score 20):

Here is some code that finds the $n$-th point in the spiral. Unfortunately it spirals the other way but perhaps it helps anyway.

```
function spiral(n)
        k=ceil((sqrt(n)-1)/2)
        t=2*k+1
        m=t^2 
        t=t-1
        if n>=m-t then return k-(m-n),-k        else m=m-t end
        if n>=m-t then return -k,-k+(m-n)       else m=m-t end
        if n>=m-t then return -k+(m-n),k else return k,k-(m-n-t) end
end
```

See http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Ulam_spiral_howto_all_numbers.svg.

Comment: I think it would be alright to negate the `y` coordinate (`y *= -1`), given that the first element is located at `(0,0)`, in order to make it spiral the other way around as the question has requested.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a no-if solution and a formula, I was able to find this one:

$A = ||x| - |y|| + |x| + |y|;$

$R = A^2 + sgn(x + y + 0.1)*(A + x - y) + 1;$

$x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

$sgn$ — [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

```
<?php

$n = 4;
$from = -intval($n / 2) - 1;
$to = -$from + ($n % 2) - 2;

for ($x = $to; $x > $from; $x--) {
    for ($y = $to; $y > $from; $y--) {
  $result = pow((abs(abs($x) - abs($y)) + abs($x) + abs($y)), 2) + abs($x + $y + 0.1) / ($x + $y + 0.1) * (abs(abs($x) - abs($y)) + abs($x) + abs($y) + $x - $y) + 1;
  echo $result . "\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

which prints

```
7   8   9   10  
6   1   2   11  
5   4   3   12  
16  15  14  13
```

https://repl.it/repls/DarkslategraySteepBluebottle

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from Brian's answer, the *formula* for it is complex. But there is a very simple *recursive algorithm* you can use:

- for each step, record both your position and your orientation
- for n = 0, start at (0,0), facing east
- for n = 1, the spiral is (0,0): east; (0,1): east
- for n > 1, calculate the spiral for n-1. Look to your right.

  - if the space is occupied by a point of the spiral, take a step forward
  - if the space is free, turn right, then take a step forward

It is very easy to extend to other starting orientations, and also to create a left turning spiral. Here is a Scala implementation of the algorithm. I tried to optimize it for readability, not efficiency.

```
object Orientation extends Enumeration {
  val north = Value("north")
  val east = Value("east")
  val south = Value("south")
  val west = Value("west")

  val orderedValues = Vector(north, east, south, west)

  def turnRight(fromOrientation: Orientation.Value): Orientation.Value = orderedValues(
    (orderedValues.indexOf(fromOrientation) + 1) % 4)

  def turnLeft(fromOrientation: Orientation.Value): Orientation.Value = orderedValues(
    (orderedValues.indexOf(fromOrientation) +3) % 4)

  def oneStepOffset(inOrientation: Orientation.Value): (Int, Int) = inOrientation match {
    case Orientation.north => (0, 1)
    case Orientation.east => (1, 0)
    case Orientation.south => (0, -1)
    case Orientation.west => (-1, 0)
  }
}

object Direction extends Enumeration {
  val straight = Value("straight")
  val right = Value("right")
  val left = Value("left")
}

def spiral(n: Int, initialOrientation: Orientation.Value = Orientation.east, turningDirection: Direction.Value = Direction.right): List[(Int, Int)] = {

  if (turningDirection == Direction.straight) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The spiral must turn left or right")
  if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The spiral only takes a positive integer as the number of steps")

  class Step(
    val position: (Int, Int),
    val orientation: Orientation.Value)

  def nextPosition(lastStep: Step, direction: Direction.Value): (Int, Int) = {
    val newOrientation = direction match {
      case Direction.straight => lastStep.orientation
      case Direction.right => Orientation.turnRight(lastStep.orientation)
      case Direction.left => Orientation.turnLeft(lastStep.orientation)
    }

    val offset = Orientation.oneStepOffset(newOrientation)

    return (
      lastStep.position._1 + offset._1,
      lastStep.position._2 + offset._2)
  }

  def takeStep(lastStep: Step, occupiedPositions: Seq[(Int, Int)]): Step = {
    val positionAfterTurning = nextPosition(lastStep, turningDirection)
    val nextStep = if (occupiedPositions.contains(positionAfterTurning)) {
      new Step(nextPosition(lastStep, Direction.straight), lastStep.orientation)
    } else {
      val newOrientation = turningDirection match {
        case Direction.left => Orientation.turnLeft(lastStep.orientation)
        case Direction.right => Orientation.turnRight(lastStep.orientation)
      }
      new Step(positionAfterTurning, newOrientation)
    }
    return nextStep
  }

  def calculateSpiral(upTo: Int): List[Step] = upTo match {
    case 0 => new Step((0, 0), initialOrientation) :: Nil
    case 1 => new Step(Orientation.oneStepOffset(initialOrientation), initialOrientation) :: new Step((0, 0), initialOrientation) :: Nil
    case x if x > 1 => {
      val spiralUntilNow = calculateSpiral(upTo - 1)
      val nextStep = takeStep(spiralUntilNow.head, spiralUntilNow.map(step => step.position))
      (nextStep :: spiralUntilNow)
    }
  }

  return (calculateSpiral(n).map(step => step.position)).reverse
}
```

Comment: I don't have the code handy, but this is basically what I ended up doing. 

By persisting a few variables it's also fairly straightforward to allow for pausing/resuming.

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation of a spiral coordinate generator based on lhf's answer:

```
def GenSpiral(x, y):
    for n in range(numpy.inf):
        k = math.ceil((math.sqrt(n) - 1) / 2.0)
        t = 2 * k + 1
        m = t ** 2
        t = t - 1
        if n >= m - t:
            yield x + k - (m - n), y - k
        else:
            m = m - t
        if n >= m - t:
            yield x + -k, y -k + (m - n)
        else:
            m = m - t
        if n >= m - t:
            yield x -k + (m - n), y + k
        else:
            yield x + k, y + k - (m - n - t)
```