# Give an example of a bijective function f: {$(x,y): x, y \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and x ≥ y} $\rightarrow \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

As the title says, I need some help finding out a function that works.

The whole exercise is to find a bijective function f: $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$x $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ $\rightarrow$ {$(x,y): x, y \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and x ≥ y} and then another function g: {$(x,y): x, y \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and x ≥ y} $\rightarrow \mathbb{Z^{+}}$

I thought of f(a,b) = (a+b, b), and managed to prove it's bijectivity, but I'm stuck on the second one. It just feels that I'm trying to fit a set in one that it's smaller, I'm not sure on how to proceed on this one.

To be clear $\mathbb{Z^{+}}$ is the set of all non-negative integers.

Comment: this one might work: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196451/bijection-from-mathbbz-to-mathbbz-times-mathbbz

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading a bit about the diagonalization argument, I believe I can find the answer on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf Z^+$ denotes the set of non-negative integers, this one is bijective:
$$f(x,y)=\tfrac12x(x+1)+y+1.$$

Comment: I made a mistake just where I was trying not to make it, Z+ its the set of all non-negative integers... But thank you, f(x,y) = 1/2x(x+1) + y would be the answer in my case.

Comment: @Erick: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If by $\mathbf Z^+$ you mean $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$, then a picture of such a mapping would look like this

\begin{array}{cc|ccccc}
  &&&& y \\
 &x \ge y& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots \\ \hline
  &0 & 0 \\
  &1 & 1 & 2 \\
x &2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  &3 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
  &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{array}

$f(x,y) = \dfrac 12 x(x+1) + y $